# Python 2d game новичок пишу 2д игру по книжке Прискоренный питон(Ерика)

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame, 2d

Получаю ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 41, in 
> al = AlienInvasion()
> File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 14, in **init**
> self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen.width, self.settings.screen_height))
> AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.

**settings.py**

```
class Settings:
    '''tipical Nastrooky'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Ініціалізувати нстройки гри'''
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.ba_color = (230, 130, 130)
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings

class AlienInvasion:
    '''Загальний класс, що керує ресурсами та поведінкою гри'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Ініціалізувати гру, створити ресурси гри'''
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen.width, self.settings.screen_height))


        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienInvasion")
        #Колір фону
        self.bg_color = (230, 130, 130)



    def run_game(self):
        '''Розпочати цикл гри'''
        while True:
            #СЛідкувати за подіями калавіатури та миші
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            
                #Наново перемалювати екран на кожній ітерації циклу
                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)


                #Останній намальований екран показати
                pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Створити екземпляр гри та запустити.
    al = AlienInvasion()
    al.run_game()
```

Comment: Мы рады, что вы пишите игру

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame

#from settings import Settings
class Settings:
    ''' tipical Nastrooky '''

    def __init__(self):
        ''' Ініціалізувати нстройки гри'''
        
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.ba_color = (230, 130, 130)
        

class AlienInvasion:
    '''Загальний класс, що керує ресурсами та поведінкою гри'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Ініціалізувати гру, створити ресурси гри'''
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
#            (self.settings.screen.width, self.settings.screen_height)
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height)     # +++
        )

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienInvasion")
        #Колір фону
        self.bg_color = (230, 130, 130)

    def run_game(self):
        '''Розпочати цикл гри'''
        while True:
            #СЛідкувати за подіями калавіатури та миші
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            
                #Наново перемалювати екран на кожній ітерації циклу
#                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
                self.screen.fill(self.settings.ba_color)                  # +++

                #Останній намальований екран показати
                pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Створити екземпляр гри та запустити.
    al = AlienInvasion()
    al.run_game()
```